# addEventListener событие change на input type file срабатывает только один раз

Tags: javascript, img

Пытаюсь разобраться с FileReader api и столкнулся с затруднением.

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    console.log('change');
    var files = evt.target.files[0]; // FileList object

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = reader.result;
        sendMessage(mainInput.value,false,img)
        clearMainInput();
        console.log(img);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(files);


  }

  document.getElementById('picturesUploadinput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect,false);
```

Картинка котика загружается только один раз.Второй раз того же котика я загрузить не могу, так как событие change не срабатывает.Какой правильный путь, сделать так что бы я мог загрузить картинку одного и того же котика два раза подряд.

Comment: все так, если файл тот же самый, то загружаться не будет. Проблема в том, что руками очистить поле вы не можете, поэтому нужно просто его пересоздавать

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4118320/5703133

Comment: можете ли вы уточнить, я не совсем понял оборот "пресоздать поле"

Comment: я скинул ссылку на английский вопрос такой же